# eclipse v4.2.1 very slow on Windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse

My Eclipse is very slow. I am using it for android projects and it is damn slow when making a build or cleaning the project. I have latest android sdk 21 and ADT 21 installed. My Laptop's configuration is :-
Dell Latitude 
4 gb ram
core i5
32 bit OS

I tried changing the eclipse.ini file but every time i increase the heap size there the eclipse does not start and shows an error "unable to run Java virtual Machine". Here is me ini file:-

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform 
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
768m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms768m
-Xm1280m
```

Please suggest some trick to make it fast. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your specs are good enough, Eclipse does lots of tasks in the background to make your life easier. Now I have been using Eclipse for more than eight years now and I have come up with the set of tuneups to make it run faster for me. I'll list them down here, you may choose to apply all of them or some of them, it is up to you.

Open the Preferences by going to the Window menu and choosing Preferences (Assuming you are using the default configuration):

1. Under General, check 'Always run in background'
2. Under General>Appearance, Un-check 'Enable animations'
3. Under General>Startup and Shutdown, disable all un-used services
4. Under General>Workspace, uncheck 'Build automatically'
5. Under Java>Editor>Content Assist, uncheck 'Enable auto activation'

I'm sure there are other things that can be tuned, I myself modify more options than the ones I've mentioned above, but they are only to suite my needs, I only highlighted ones that would affect speed. What you would also need to check for is essentially any option that automates actions for you while using Eclipse, and make then decision if you can live with that option being done manually.

You may also want to make sure that your laptop is set to use High-Performance for the power configuration. Some laptops will run with half the CPUs' power while under other power configurations.

Finally, I would recommend you export your tuned up preferences into a file so that you can import them into other workspaces in the future.

*To export Go to File menu>Export>General>Preferences*

Answer (score 0):

I like your name ;) Anyways, There are a few things you can check and do to make it faster.

1. Check the power plan of your laptop. Keep it plugged in and keep the plan to High Performance. That significantly increases the performance on my case.
2. Eclipse is slow. Take it for granted. You will find it even slower when using DDMS for debugging and logging purposes. What you can do is go to **TASK MANAGER** Find eclipse in the processes list. *Right Click* on it and go to *Set Affinity*. Select any other core than **CPU 0**. You can always set multiple cores to it.
3. If during the process of executing your android program, your AVD is taking too long, try increasing the RAM size and reduce the Screen Size of your AVD. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, i had same problem. Eclipse android project compilation and packaging is too boooooring. I changed IDE from Eclipse to Intellij IDEA - it works a bit better, not the best compilation and packaging speed, but also better then Eclipse. Try it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ADT 22.0 or above. My application includes AdMob and during the running or debugging step, the class files in admob jar are converted to dex files.

I removed the admob code and the jar from my project temporarily and the build process speeded up again.